# JBoss AS stop working while sending SOAP messages

Tags: web-services, soap, jboss

I am using JBoss AS 5.0.0.
I start it in "default" configuration with some web services being deployed as a *.ear file.
Client sends SOAP-messages and get valid responses an communicate with server in such way.
But at some time an exception is thrown and the server is responsive no more.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    17:58:00,546 ERROR [STDERR] 12.09.2012 17:58:00 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:112)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:284)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:339)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:481)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:402)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:97)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:319)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
        ... 31 more
18:02:00,482 ERROR [STDERR] 12.09.2012 18:02:00 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:365)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:277)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:457)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLReaderException: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory$Zephyr.doCreate(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:334)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.doCreate(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.create(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:301)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:360)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLReaderImpl.java:197)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLReaderImpl.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory$Zephyr.reuse(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:342)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory$Zephyr.doCreate(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:325)
        ... 35 more
```

In what way should I investigate or other advices would be appreciated much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with VM Ware Player settings. As I use VM Ware I should configure network settings. The Network was configured to use unneccessary proxy. And it seems to me some soap messages were lost due to incorrect network connection. After removing this proxy settings an error is not reproduced.